# drawing marbles with different probabilities

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose I have $N$ marbles ($m_1$ to $m_N$).
The chance that I take the $i$-th marble $m_i$ is $p(0,i)$ (adding up to $1$).
If I now take a marble (say the marble with number $M_1$) out and want to take a second one, the chances, for all $i<>M_1$, have changed to $p(1,i)=\frac{p(0,i)}{1-p(0,M_1)}$, again adding up to 1 (and $p(1,M_1)=0$). 
If I want to take a third one, again the chances will have chanced, depending on the first 2 I took out.

Now my question is: what is the chance, when I take $K$ marbles out of a bag containing $N$ marbles, that marble $m_1$ is not taken? I'm looking for a result in terms of the original chances $p(0,i)$.

For $p(0,i)=\frac{1}{N}$ this is the traditional problem.

Just so that you don't wonder about the marbles having different probabilities: the question comes from a different perspective: I'm trowing darts at balloons of different lengths hanging in line and have therefor different chances of hitting them. When one is hit, it will disappear and the other balloons will again form a line (so no gaps).

Thanks in advance

Comment: The same kind of approach works.  Although the probability of picking the first marble changes over the taking of $K$ marbles, the event that the first marble is not taken is the product of the probabilities that it is not taken on the first step, that it is not taken on the second step, etc.

Comment: Of course, the same kind of approach works. My question is perhaps not stated clearly enough: what does the chance looks like as a function of the $p(0,i)$?

Comment: Does the order in which the first several marbles are drawn affect the probability that one of the remaining marbles are drawn, or just the set of marbles already drawn?

Comment: In the latter case, we have: for any $T\subset S$ and $T\ne S$, $\sum\limits_{x\in S}p(T,x)=1\text{ and }x\in T\implies p(T,x)=0$.

Comment: The order is not relevant, just the set is relevant. If I draw marbles $M_1 .. M_t$ (and the first marble is not among those), the chance for the first marble not to be picked the next time is $\frac{1-p(0,M_1)-..-p(0,M_t)-p(0,1)}{ 1-p(0,M_1)-..-p(0,M_t)}$